# HTML div formatting not resulting in desired output

Tags: angularjs, html

I have two an array with two sets of data and I want to display each set in a separate column, in the following format:

```
Set1    Set 2
1       ABC
2       DEF
        GEF
3       HIJ
        JKL
4       MNO
        PQR
```

Instead, my data appears as follows:

```
Set 1   Set 2  
1       ABC
2       DEF
GEF     3
HIJ
JKL      4
MNO
PQR
```

How do I make my data appear correctly (ie, make sure all data from Set 2 falls in the right column) using the  tag, assigning "class = col-xs-4" to the first set and "class= col-xs-8" to the second?  Here's my code as it stands now:

```
                                <div ng-switch="hoursOfOp[0]">
                                <div ng-switch-when = "Not available"><class="col-xs-4 align-right">{{hoursOfOp[0]}}</div>
                                <div ng-switch-default>
                                    <div ng-repeat="hours in hoursOfOp">
                                        <div class="col-xs-4 align-left">{{hours.day}}</div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-8 align-left no-padding" ng-repeat="time in hours.time">{{time}}</div>
                                    </div>                                  
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: That's because when a col does not fit on the same row, it goes to the next one. What you can do is to make another div inside the div with col-xs-8 and put the ng-repeat there, as a list or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, that's because when a col does not fit on the same row, it goes to the next one. What you can do is to make another div inside the div with col-xs-8 and put the ng-repeat there, as a list or something.

Keep in mind that ng-repeat repeats the element it is put in. So in your case, the flow is the following:

- creates the col-xs-4 with the 1 value on first row
- creates the col-xs-8 with the ABC value on first row, since there is space
- creates the col-xs-4 with the 2 value on the next row, because there isn't space above
- creates the col-xs-8 with the DEF value on the same row, since there is space
- creates the col-xs-8 with the GEF value **on the NEXT ROW**, since there isn't space above
- from this point, everything gets messed up.

The below example is working :)

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.hoursOfOp = [
    {id: 1, time: ["ABC"]}, 
    {id: 2, time: ["DEF", "GEF"]}, 
    {id: 3, time: ["HIJ", "JKL"]}, 
    {id: 4, time: ["MNO", "PQR"]}]
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="hours in hoursOfOp" class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 stuff">{{ hours.id }}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 stuff">
          <div ng-repeat="v in hours.time">
            {{ v }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```